# WHat's the exact bug fix kernel version?

Tags: vulnerability

As of now we have UBUNTU 14.04.3 LTS, UBUNTU 16.04 LTS installed on VMWARE Machine and Physical Server.

Also we are using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Cloud images.

Could you please let me know what's the exact Kernel Versions we need to install on the server inorder to fix the images for Meltdown and Spectre CVE-2017-5753 and Meltdown CVE-2017-5754?

Please share the exact kernel versions for OS

UBUNTU 14.04.3 LTS, UBUNTU 16.04 LTS
CLoud OS Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: The versions if any are listed in the Ubuntu Security Notice (USN) pages.

Comment: a quick startpage.com search of "ubuntu meltdown spectre status" revealed as line 3 --  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown  (this link is updated as more info is available; and kernel version varies on architecture as well as version)